# How to convert a string to class Name and vice versa

Tags: java, android

I have a number of activities (Main1, Main2...Mainn) managed from a superClass so what I'm trying to do but fail is to Move from Main i to Main i+1 thru a button (nextPage), and in order not to repeat the same code n times I tried to convert the ClassName into Integer to get its number (i) and after that i concatenate that number (i+1) into a string and after that convert the string into Class type to call it from the Button (nextPage). here is the code :    I edited my code an this is the solution that's working perfectly:

```
str = getClass().getName();// this code line converts the class name to string
    int num = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1)); //this extracts integer from string

    str1 = "com.example.Test.Main_" + (num + 1);//this is a pure concatenation
    str2 = "com.example.Test.Main_" + (num - 1);//this is a pure concatenation

    try {
        nextClass = Class.forName(str1);// this how to convert string to a class name

        i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextClass);
                startActivity(i);
                str = nextClass.getName();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);

            }
        });

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: I got this  error:   Multiple markers at this line
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized
 
 - string cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation of [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29): The characters in the string *must all be decimal digits*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current class name you should use this:

```
String str = getClass().getName();
```

Now str is Main1, Main2, ... . So you cannot parse it because it is not String. You can rename your classes with this format: Main_1, Main_2, ... and change your code :

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1));
str1="Main_"+(num+1);
Class nextClass=Class.forName("com.example.Test."+ str1);
```

Comment: I got this error msg:   Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized

Comment: I have edited my answer. I had forgotten to put "_" after Main. So if you have Main_1, Main_2, ... in com.example.Test, in must work.

Comment: Thank you man I edited my question with the perfect code that's working, have a look

Comment: Its good but don't forget to control your num. if num is currently 0, num-1 will point to Main_-1. A similar check is needed for last activity. Finally if it is useful mark this as answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. should work

```
String str = getClass().toString();
Integer num = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
str1="Main"+ String.valueOf(num+1);
Class<?> nextClass;
    try {
        nextClass = Class.forName("com.example.Test" + str );


    i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextClass);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);

        }
    });

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i got this message error : Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized

Comment: check the answer now.. i have edited it. Im assuming ur class names would be `TestMain1` `TestMain2`..

Comment: the package name is com.example.Test, the classes are MAin1, main2... and the error mainly is in this code line Class nextClass=Class.forName("com.example"+ str1);

Comment: @AndroDev ahh... missed a "." there dude..Change the line `nextClass = Class.forName("com.example.Test." + str );` 
Now will work

Comment: MAN it's working perfectly now, see the code n my edited question, many thanks

Comment: `snake_case is` not a good naming convention for class names, use `uppercamel case` and similar solution to solve it :-/